The line-clamp Tailwind CSS class not functioning correctly at all in my Next.js application
I am working on displaying Shad CN cards with the same  height and width in my Next.js application, but text overflow is preventing this. How can I control the text overflow in the CardTitle and CardDescription components to ensure they fit within the card dimensions?
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"


export function MyCard({ obj }) {
  return (
    <Card className="text-white bg-[#0a0a0a] w-[350px]">
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle >
          <p >
            {obj.title}
          </p>
        </CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>
        <p >
            {obj.desc}
          </p>
        </CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent className="flex justify-center items-center">
        <img
          src={obj.imgCover}  // Replace with your image path
          className="w-full h-auto"  // Adjust dimensions as needed
        />
      </CardContent>
      <CardFooter className="flex justify-between">
        <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
        <Button>Deploy</Button>
      </CardFooter>
    </Card>
  )
}


I didn't add any classes directly to the CardTitle and CardDescription components and instead used a  tag within them, I am still experiencing issues with text overflow. I have also installed the tailwindcss/line-clamp plugin and included it in my tailwind.config.js file.

Can you share the current UI or a working code snippet so that we can understand your problem better?
